# How can I make my disabled button not change color when there's a hover with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried this CSS:

```
html.dark .btn:hover:not(disabled),
html.dark .btn:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #222222;
  *background-color: #151515;
}
html.dark .btn.disabled,
html.dark .btn[disabled] {
  color: red;
  background-color: #222222;
  *background-color: #151515;
}
```

But still when I hover over the button I see the color change from red to white. Note that it's correctly picking up the fact it's disabled. I am using:

```
disabled="disabled"
```

in my button.

Comment: Please post enough of your HTML to accurately reproduce your problem; ideally create a snippet to provide a (minimal) live demo ([edit] your question, and hit the `<>` button in the editor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `.btn:hover:not(:disabled),`

A small example

Your example didn't work because you are using `.btn:hover:not(disabled)` you have to use a pseudo class to achieve what you need [reference pseudo classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```css
button:hover:not(:disabled){
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Not disabled</button>
<button disabled>disabled</button>
```

Comment: Darn, beaten me to it :D

Comment: It's not worth a separate answer, but it's maybe worth pointing out that `disabled` is an attribute, so `:not([disabled])` will (or should) also work. For this to be a complete answer, though, you really should explain why the posted code didn't work for the OP. I know *you* know, since you answered, but other than a 'do this' the OP's not really learned anything from your answer (yet).

Comment: @DavidThomas post it as your answer i din't know about that

Comment: It's really not worth a separate answer, the explanation for why the originally-posted code didn't work would also cover the alternative. :)

Comment: @Akshay - This is a good answer but it doesn't duplicate my code. Can you have a look at my code which is a button with the btn class and disabled="disabled"  I tried to edit your code snippet but cannot. Is there some other way you can link to an example. Thanks very much.